# Adding Sencha Touch Charts 2.0 Beta to Sencha Touch 2 Project

Tags: extjs, charts, touch, sencha-touch-2

I'm a web dev rookie and I'm trying to include Sencha Touch Charts (v2, beta) into my sencha app which works fine so far. 
Can someone please explain the necessary steps in order to do that? And in a way that's appropriate for total beginners :)

Here's what I've done:

1. Downloaded the "Sencha Touch Charts 2 Beta"
2. Copied the contents from the 3 folders at: **touch-charts-2.0.0-beta/src/**  into my project's **touch/src/** folder

Is that correct?? SHould I now be able to instatiate using xtype: 'chart' and so on? Cause I've tried that and got these errors:

**TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'Ext.chart.series.Series')**

No clue how to fix that. I really need an easy explanation on how to set everything up including referencing the js-files from the index.html if thats necessary. I'm not doing it at the moment.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Oh yea and I've built the app in the first place (back then without the charts library) by using the sencha command line tools. 

So a tutorial which starts from having a running app without the charts lib would be really helpful.

Comment: FYI I switched to g.Raphael since Sencha Charts will either cost you or put the whole project under GPL